# How to Wrap Backbone Collection into JSON object?

Tags: jquery, json, backbone.js

I've extended the Backbone Collection class to include a "save" method, which is essentially a proxy to sync. Whenever, "save" is executed an array of objects is submitted to the backend. However, the backend is not currently structured to handle straight collections, it expects objects. Does anyone have any suggestions on how can I "wrap" this collection in a object?

I tried:

```
var objectCollection = {};
objectCollection['key'] = backboneCollection.models;
```

But the above results in "*model does not have a toJSON method*" error -- since I'm simply proxying sync. Thanks.

Comment: While you could use the JSON object from json.org (it has a stringify method), this still wouldn't get you there. This is because JSON, by definition, cannot represent functions, and I'm supposing `backboneCollection.models` is going to have functions in it, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To provide a custom format for `Backbone.sync`, you will have to pass your data as a JSON string and provide the correct `contentType`. Something like this:

```
var M=Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/echo/json/',

    save: function() {
        var data={}, opts= {};
        data.key=this.toJSON();

        opts.contentType = 'application/json';
        opts.data = JSON.stringify(data);

        Backbone.sync.call(this,'update',this, opts);
    }
});
```

And a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xx4pr/ (check your console to see the request)

Comment: Thanks for the example/fiddle, it was very helpful in understanding the approach. I wasn't aware that sync accepted and processed data within the options param -- I thought that it only took success & error callbacks.